Adding a scrollbar to a column in Flet Python
I am creating a Barcelona App in flet, but i am unable to get the column of the fixtures to scroll, when u run the program, you will realize it.
I have tried to use the "scroll=ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS", and i also set expand to true , i increased the height, i have tried everything given online, but i need help
Code: https://github.com/Manas-Sujal/Barcelona-App-With-Error
I apologize for asking such a favour, but please help .....

My best guess is that your container (schedule_widget) doesn't have a fixed height, stopping flet from being able to properly calculate the scrollable area, you can fix it via the code snippet below:
schedule_widget = ft.Column(controls=[ft.Text("")], spacing=10)

schedule_main_widget = ft.Container(
    content=schedule_widget,
    height=500,
    padding=ft.padding.all(10),
    border=ft.border.all(1, ft.colors.GREY),
    scroll=ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS,
)

schedule_mainest_widget = ft.Column(
    controls=[schedule_main_widget],
    expand=True,
)

page.update()


This doesnt work, this error pops up,
schedule_main_widget = ft.Container(
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scroll'

Fisrt. I think set schedule_widget as ListView and simplify struckture is better.
Second. I add function to changeing tab change_tab now tab is not in tab, but setting visible/non by this function. For me this works fine.
import flet as ft
from threading import Thread
import threading

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import win32api
import requests
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

global close
from time import sleep

close = False


def scrap():
    global t, close
    while (close == False):
        global t, page, schedule_widget
        if t.selected_index == 0:
            url = 'https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/schedule'
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            #### Dates #####
            dates_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-result-list__fixture-date")
            dates = []

            for date in dates_tag:
                dates.append(date.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            #### Time of Matches ####
            times_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-info__time")
            times = []

            for time in times_tag:
                times.append(time.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            #### Name of Competition #####
            competition_names_tag = soup.find_all("span", class_="fixture-result-list__name visually-hidden")
            competition_names = []

            for competition_name in competition_names_tag:
                competition_names.append(competition_name.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            ##### Match Day Number  #####
            matchdays_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-result-list__stage")
            matchdays = []

            for matchday in matchdays_tag:
                matchdays.append(matchday.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            ##### Name of Home Team ####
            home_names_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-info__name fixture-info__name--home")
            home_names = []

            for home_name in home_names_tag:
                home_names.append(home_name.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            ##### Name of Away Team ####
            away_names_tag = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixture-info__name fixture-info__name--away")
            away_names = []

            for away_name in away_names_tag:
                away_names.append(away_name.text.strip().replace("\n", ""))

            ##### Logo of Home Team
            home_logo_divs = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "fixture-info__badge fixture-info__badge--home"})
            home_logo = []

            for home_logo_div in home_logo_divs:
                home_logo.append(home_logo_div.find('img').attrs['srcset'].split(",")[1].replace("2x", ""))

            ##### Logo of Away Team
            away_logo_divs = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "fixture-info__badge fixture-info__badge--away"})
            away_logo = []

            for away_logo_div in away_logo_divs:
                away_logo.append(away_logo_div.find('img').attrs['srcset'].split(",")[1].replace("2x", ""))

            schedule_widget.controls.clear()
            schedule_widget.controls.append(ft.Text(""))

            for x in range(len(home_names)):
                match = ft.Container(content=
                ft.Row([
                    ft.Text(f"{home_names[x]} v/s {away_names[x]}   |  "),
                    ft.Text(f"{dates[x]} | {times[x]}")
                ], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    expand=1
                ),
                    padding=ft.padding.only(30, 10, 30, 10),
                    expand=1,
                    border_radius=10,
                    border=ft.border.all(3, ft.colors.GREY)
                )
                schedule_widget.controls.append(match)

            schedule_widget.update()



def main(page: ft.Page):
    global t, thread2, close, schedule_widget, schedule_main_widget, schedule_mainest_widget
    page.title = "F.C. Barcelona - Manas Sujal"
    #page.window.width = GetSystemMetrics(0) - 50
    page.window.width = 500
    #page.window.height = GetSystemMetrics(1) - 70
    page.window.height = 600
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.DARK

    page.window.resizable = True
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    def handle_window_event(e):
        if e.data == "close":
            page.window.visible = False
            page.update()
            page.window.destroy()
            page.update()
            global close
            close = True

    page.window.prevent_close = True
    page.window.on_event = handle_window_event
    top_column = ft.Container(  # begin=ft.alignment.center_left , end=ft.alignment.center_left
        gradient=ft.RadialGradient(radius=5.8, colors=["#680630", "#06167D"]),
        content=ft.Column(controls=[
            ft.Text(""),
            ft.Row([

                ft.Text("     "),
                ft.Text(
                    spans=[
                        ft.TextSpan(
                            "F.C. Barcelona",
                            ft.TextStyle(
                                size=55,
                                decoration=ft.TextDecoration.UNDERLINE
                            ))]),
                ft.Text("     "),

            ], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER),
            ft.Text(""),
        ]))
    schedule_widget = ft.ListView(expand=1, spacing=10, padding=1)

    page.update()

    def change_tab(e):
        idx = e.control.selected_index
        schedule_widget.visible = False

        if idx == 0:
            schedule_widget.visible = True

    t = ft.Tabs(
        tab_alignment=ft.TabAlignment.CENTER,
        selected_index=0,
        animation_duration=0,
        indicator_color="#680630",
        label_text_style=ft.TextStyle(
            size=20,
        ),
        label_color="#0c2bf5",
        unselected_label_color="#c20757",
        scrollable=True,
        on_click=lambda e: change_tab(e),

        tabs=[
            ft.Tab(text="     Fixtures     "),

            ft.Tab(text="     Results     "),

            ft.Tab(text="     Tables     "),

            ft.Tab(text="     Players     "),
        ],
    )

    page.add(top_column,t,  schedule_widget)


    scrap()
    page.update()
    #thread2 = threading.Thread(target=scrap)
    #thread2.start()

ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")



